# Trying to create box container around text on Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I have some text on top of my images for my carousel shown below.

[image]

I want to add a box around the text with some opacity so it is easier to read. I've tried some things but the box takes a weird shape as it starts to scale down.

Here is my html for my Carousel:

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
     <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <img src="img/golden_egg3.jpg" class="img-responsive first-slide" alt="First slide">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="caption-one">
                            <h1>The right Wealth Advisor can make a big difference.</h1>
                            <br>
                            <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg hvr-underline-from-left" role="button">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <img src="img/graph_in_hand3.jpg" class="img-responsive second-slide" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="caption-two">
                            <h1>Personal Wealth Planning is not<br> just charts and graphs, it's about<br> taking control of your financial future.</h1>
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary hvr-underline-from-left" href="contact.html" role="button">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <img src="img/jar_with_coins3.jpg" class="img-responsive third-slide" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="caption-three">
                            <h1>Successful investing takes<br> time, discipline and patience.</h1>
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary hvr-underline-from-left" href="contact.html" role="button">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</header>
```

For my class `.caption-one` which is my first image I applied the following CSS:

```
.caption-one {
      background-color: #282828;
      opacity: 0.75;
      padding-left: 2%;
      margin-right: 38%;
      padding-bottom: 2%;
      width: 40%;
}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Looks okay but definitely could be better. Here it is on mobile:

[image]

Even worse. I have no clue why my button is so big because I use this same button for the contact page and it scales very nicely. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your code, Hope this work.

```css
.carousel-caption{
      background-color: #282828;
      opacity: 0.75;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
  h1{
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h1>The right Wealth Advisor can make a big difference.</h1>
    <br>
    <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg hvr-underline-from-left" role="button">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```